# Cannot import third party module in Scala worksheet VSCode

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code

I have used Scala 3 in VSCode with metals via Windows Subsystem for Linux.

First, I created the cats effect 3 project using `sbt new typelevel/ce3.g8`. There are Main.scala file which can be run just fine using sbt run.

Then, I created the scala worksheet to try some code. However, I can't import cats into scala worksheet. I wonder why?

I have seen similar question which can be solved by adjusting Scala worksheet setting `Run type` from `REPL` to `plain` in Intellij idea, but this setting doesn't seem to exist in VSCode.

Thanks in advance guys!

[image]

Comment: Not sure to understand: is Cats library in your dependencies?

Comment: Does the import works in the `Main` class? If so, are you sure you created the **worksheet** in the correct folder and with the correct name? If no, then did you already imported the project in **metals**?

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes, cats library is in my dependencies, I can run Main.scala file which depend on cats and it can run just fine.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes, 
1. the import work in Main class
2. the worksheet I created is .sc extension and it can evaluate simple expression
3. I have already import the project with metals.

Comment: @KorntewinBoonchuay I am not able to reproduce the problem... however, I have my worksheet inside the `src/main/scala` folder as well as naming it `Test.worksheet.sc` _(note the **worksheet** in the middle)_ as mentioned in the docs: https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode/#worksheets - Are, you sure your setup is the same?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue with a worksheet in `src\test\myworksheet.sc` (no dependencies would resolve). When moved to `src\test\scala\myworksheet.sc` it worked fine.  (See @luis response as well)